# SQLAlchemy: Increment primary key based on previous data

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm connecting to a postgres docker container from a flask application.

After every insert operation, the primary key increments to the next value.
So if I insert 5 records and delete all of them, and then insert a new record, it's primary key will be 6.

Is there a way I can change this to 1 since there are no other records in the table?

Below is my code for `models.py`:

```
from app import db

class Cats(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "cats"
    id    = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name  = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    breed = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

And `database.py`:

```
from app import db

def get_all(model):
    data = model.query.all()
    return data


def add_instance(model, **kwargs):
    instance = model(**kwargs)
    db.session.add(instance)
    commit_changes()


def delete_instance(model, id):
    model.query.filter_by(id=id).delete()
    commit_changes()


def edit_instance(model, id, **kwargs):
    instance = model.query.filter_by(id=id).all()[0]
    for attr, new_value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(instance, attr, new_value)
    commit_changes()


def commit_changes():
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the primary key is to identify your records "forever".
Once given to a specific record, a primary key should not be "reused" after the record was deleted.

Because when you add records 1,2,3,4,5 and delete the record 3, you also should not keep track of the fact that "3" is now available again.

Or, in other words: primary keys are not meant for "counting".